# How to read the first element of all Rows in a text file and then iterate over it in Powershell scripting?

Tags: arrays, powershell, collections, iteration, powershell-3.0

I am a complete newbie in Powershell scripting and programming. I need to do the Following:

- There is text file which has number of rows, each row has elements separated by commas. Now, some rows always start with "BB" and there can be hundreds of "BB" rows. When its "BB", i need to do some changes etc.

I want to iterate over all the rows and if it starts with "BB", then i will do some stuff. Below is just a test code as I have no idea of what to do here. How, can i do it in most effective way, so that it is fast and has less performance 
overhead.

Update: Now, the issue is that the date in the first instance(its strange) of "BB" row is not getting updated. This is the updated code, i have written:

Now, should i write out-file after the "Foreach" loop as it will write to the file again and again. Also, when to use pipeline character (|).

```
$path = 'C:\CE\InputFile\file_test1.txt'
$Filedata = Get-Content $path

$CurrentDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yymmdd")

foreach($Row in $Filedata){
if($Row.split(",")[0] -eq "BB")
{
    $Row2Date = $Row.Split(",")[4] 
    $Temp = $Filedata -replace $Row2Date, $CurrentDate | 

Out-File C:\outdata\outputfile1.txt

}

}
```

---

```
AA, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5.....
BB, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5.....
CC, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5.....
DD, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5.....
BB, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5.....
```

Comment: If the file is comma delimited why not use Import-Csv inserting dummy headers if neccessary?

Comment: Hi @LotPings, thats the issue. I cant insert dummy headers in the text file.

Comment: The month format specifier must be uppercase `(Get-Date).ToString("yyMMdd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the requirements changed I post a new answer.
Since you want to change the 5th field I extended the sample file

```
## Q:\Test\2018\04\30\SO_50095738_2.ps1
$FilePath1 = 'C:\CE\InputFile\file_test1.txt'
$FilePath2 = 'C:\outdata\outputfile1.txt'

$FileData1 = Get-Content $FilePath1
$CurrentDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyMMdd")

$FileData2 = ForEach($Row in $Filedata1){
    If ($Row.split(",")[0] -eq "BB"){
       $Row  -replace ($Row.Split(",")[4]), $CurrentDate
    } else {
       $Row
    }
} 
Out-File -FilePath $FilePath2 -InputObject $FileData2
```

Sample output

```
AA, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5.....
BB, field1, field2, field3,180402, field5.....
CC, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5.....
DD, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5.....
BB, field1, field2, field3,180402, field5.....
```

Comment: thanks for the correct answer. It works like a charm! Now, all the "BB" records have updated dates.

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need to insert Headers in the file, `Import-Csv` can handle
  this.
- You can remove headers, see the commented out variant.
- It might be an issue that `Export-Csv` double quotes all fields.
- This also can be handled if neccessary.

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\04\30\SO_50095738.ps1
$FilePath = '.\TestFile001.txt' 
$FileData = Import-Csv $FilePath -Header H0,H1,H2,H3
$test1 = 'test1'

ForEach($row in $FileData ) {
  If ($row.H0 -eq 'BB' ) {
    $row.H2 = $test1
  }
}
$FileData | Export-csv $FilePath -NoTypeInformation

## Variant with NoHeader
# $FileData|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInfo|Select -Skip 1|Set-Content $FilePath

## Variant with no header and no quotes
# ($FileData|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInfo).Replace('","',', ').Trim('"')|Select -Skip 1|Set-Content $FilePath

Get-Content $FilePath
```

Sample output:

```
"H0","H1","H2","H3"
"AA","field1","field 2","field 3....."
"BB","field1","test1","field 3....."
"CC","field1","field 2","field 3....."
"DD","field1","field 2","field 3....."
"BB","field1","test1","field 3....."
```

Comment: Now, one other issue is that, the loop runs again and again and i want to save the updated output file in a directory. Can it update for ex("500 "BB" records in one go and then save the file output file , once in the directory)   Out-File C:\PS\outfile1.txt

Comment: Sorry I can't follow. Did the script work as you required? If yes consider to accept and/or upvote. Otherwise if you want to save to another file/path create a var for this and use them. As is - the script will change **all** rows that meet the condition in the `$FileData` variable in memory until you save back to whatever place.

Comment: No, there are many items in a single row and that changes in other files, so i cant use headers .

Answer (score 0):

Use split to get the first "column"

```
$FileContent =Get-Content -Path "SomePath\test.txt"
foreach ($Row in $FileContent) {
    if ($Row.Split(",")[0] -eq "BB") {
        $NewRow = $Row -replace "BB", "XX"
        $FileContent = $FileContent.Replace($Row,$NewRow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, only the first "BB" records updated, but other "instances" are not changed.

Comment: I did not solve my issue. Maybe the variable "$Row" does not contain thr records in the file. Also, how can we insert rows in the array based on the newline/eol.
if ($Filedata.Split(",")[0] -eq "BB") , this does not find my "BB" records.

Comment: you can not use th variable which contains the whole data. loop thru the rows and split the row, look at my example

Comment: Now, one other issue is that, the loop runs again and again and i want to save the updated output file in a directory. Can it update for ex("500 "BB" records in one go and then save the file output file , once in the directory)   Out-File C:\PS\outfile1.txt